# getDatabase called recursively error using Room on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to run a query using Room. However when I try to run the query I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:357)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion.execute(CoroutinesRoom.kt:45)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom.execute(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.UserDao_Impl.addNewUser(UserDao_Impl.java:132)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.LoanHubDatabase$UserDatabaseCallback.populateDatabase(LoanHubDatabase.kt:71)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.LoanHubDatabase$UserDatabaseCallback$onOpen$$inlined$let$lambda$1.invokeSuspend(LoanHubDatabase.kt:55)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:330)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:49)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.LoanHubDatabase$UserDatabaseCallback.onOpen(LoanHubDatabase.kt:54)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.LoanHubDatabase_Impl$1.onOpen(LoanHubDatabase_Impl.java:63)
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:136)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:142)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:428)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.UserDao_Impl.getUsernamePassword(UserDao_Impl.java:207)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.UserRepository.getUsernamePassword(UserRepository.kt:15)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.models.UserViewModel.getUsernamePassword(UserViewModel.kt:31)
        at com.uwi.loanhub.LoginActivityNew$onCreate$2.onClick(LoginActivityNew.kt:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

The error appears when this is called:

```
var userHolderList:List<User> = userViewModel.getUsernamePassword(editText_username_Login_Activity.text.toString(), functions.encryptSys(editText_password_Login_Activity.text.toString()))
```

I have another method which is used to insert data into the database and it works without any troubles. There I am not sure why the error appears on this method.
The Database call is as follows:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class LoanHubDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun UserDao(): UserDao


    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: LoanHubDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): LoanHubDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    LoanHubDatabase::class.java,
                    "LoanHub_Database"
                ).addCallback(UserDatabaseCallback(scope)).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }

        }

    }

    private class UserDatabaseCallback(private val scope: CoroutineScope) :
        RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {
                    populateDatabase(database.UserDao())
                }

            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        suspend fun populateDatabase(userDao: UserDao) {


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `RoomDatabase.Callback`, you cannot use Room, as Room is not ready yet. You can use the supplied `SupportSQLiteDatabase` to perform required operations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I am not fully understanding what you are saying the problem is.

Comment: @NicoleFoster In your `UserDatabaseCallback`, you are attempting to use the `RoomDatabase` (`INSTANCE`) and its DAO (`database.UserDao()`). That is not supported. Your `onOpen()` function is passed a `SupportSQLiteDatabase` that you can use instead.

Comment: Okay, when I do that then I get: ```Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.```

Comment: @NicoleFoster: Your `CoroutineScope` has a default dispatcher of `Dispatchers.Main`, apparently. Use `scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` or something to arrange to do the work on a background thread.

Comment: yeah I tried using ```(Dispatchers.IO)``` and it is is giving the same error. Is there a simpler way to do this kind of thing. The thing is when I insert, it works fine. But to do a simple query I am getting this problem.

Comment: @NicoleFoster: "and it is is giving the same error" -- at this point, I recommend that you post a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] that shows your current code and a complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: one thing. How can I make the getUsernamePassword function to use Dispatcher.IO like the insert function. ```fun addUser(user: User) = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        repository.addNewUser(user)
    }

    fun getUsernamePassword(inputUserName:String, inputPassword:String):List<User>{

        return repository.getUsernamePassword(inputUserName, inputPassword)


    }```